# getting identity of the saved record

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
                        Feature feature = new Feature();
                        feature.vcr_FeaturesName = AddedNode.ToString();
                        feature.int_ParentId = 0;
                        feature.int_CreatedBy = 1;
                        feature.dtm_CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                        FeatureRepository.Add(feature);
                        FeatureRepository.Save();
```

i am using linq how would i going to get the identity in the code above.

Comment: Please explain in detail and post more code!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call submitchanges() in LINQ to SQL, it refreshes the key; think that's the same for LINQ to entities.  Your code is wrapping this process but what are those methods doing?